# Is and As keyword in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting

I am trying to get understanding of the difference between `is` and `as` keyword in `C#`

On googling & reading few articles, I got the understanding as below:-

- `is`checks whether the type of an given object is compatible with the new object type. This is a Boolean type..returns either true or false
- `as` checks whether the type of an given object is compatible with the new object type. It returns non-null if given object is compatible with new one, else null.. This throws an exception.

So taking this below I was trying.

```
class Customer
{

}

class Client
{

}

Main()
{
  Customer cu = new Customer();  
  Client cl = new Client();

 //usage of is 

  var flag = cu is Customer;
  Console.Writeline(flag); //true

 flag = cu is Client;
 Console.writeline(flag); // false

//usage of as
var obj = cu as Customer; 
Console.writeline(obj);


//on the below statement, I was expecting an exception on run time.
 var obj1 = cu as Client;
 //#checkPoint but the above line is giving me Compile time error.

}
```

It sounds confusing to me why I am getting compile time error on *#checkPoint* instead based on my understanding I was expecting a run time error as customerObj(cu) is not compatible with Client.

Any suggestion(s) highly appreciated.

Comment: 'as' is basically used when casting.  'is' is basically used when checking the type. Not to oversimplify.

Comment: Change `var obj ` to `Customer obj` and it will become clearer why you get the compile error.

Answer (score 2):

The specification defines when a cast of the form `obj as T` is valid:

**7.10.11 The as operator**

> An identity (§6.1.1), implicit nullable (§6.1.4), implicit reference
>   (§6.1.6), boxing (§6.1.7), explicit nullable (§6.2.3), explicit
>   reference (§6.2.4), or unboxing (§6.2.5) conversion exists from E to
>   T.

In

```
var obj1 = cu as Client;
```

There is no implicit conversion so you need an explicit reference conversion between `cu` and `Client`.

The specification defines the explicit reference conversions:

**6.2.4 Explicit reference conversions**

- From object and dynamic to any other reference-type.
- From any class-typeS to any class-typeT, provided S is a base class of T.

Neither of these apply so the cast is invalid. The simplest fix is to change the type of `cu` to object:

```
object cu = new Customer();
```

at runtime `cu as Client` will evaluate to `null`.

Comment: Sorry!! I checked this. still getting Compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

It's giving you a compile time error, because the type of `obj` is `Customer` and whatever comes out of `cu as Client` will be of type `Client`.

You will not get an exception at runtime even if you assign to a variable of type `Client` though. You quoted it yourself:

> else null

It will simply result in `null`.

Comment: I corrected my post. Taking your post into consideration this is what I was expecting but my confustion why I am getting Compile time error

Answer (score 1):

When you say `var obj = cu as Client` you basically trying to cast `cu` instance to `Client`, and since it is not inherited from `Client`, it returns null.

It is more convenient to give this example for a usecase:

Let's say you have a base class of `BaseClass`:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        protected BaseClass()
        {
        }
    }
```

and Let's say you have two types derived from `BaseClass`, `Sub1` and `Sub2`:

```
public class Sub1 : BaseClass {

}

public class Sub2 : BaseClass {

}
```

And you have a method in somewhere that takes a BaseClass object and do some instructions according to its sub classes.

```
private void Method(BaseClass base) {
     var sub1 = base as Sub1;
     var sub2 = base as Sub2;

     if(sub1 != null) {
           // do something specific
     }
     if(sub2 != null) {
           // do something specific
     }
     else
          throw new SubTypeIsNotSupportedException();
}
```

However `is` is just for checking an instance type.

```
if(anInstance is Sub1) {
     Console.WriteLine("It is Sub1!");
}
if(anInstance is Sub2) {
     Console.WriteLine("It is Sub2!");
}
else {
     Console.WriteLine("I don't know what it is!");
}
```

Comment: Please check this link https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/532831/Use-of-Is-and-As-operators-in-Csharp

Comment: Yes thats what I'm trying to explain is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to cast your "cu" in a dynamic object?

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Customer cu = new Customer();
        Client cl = new Client();

        //usage of is 

        var flag = cu is Customer;
        Console.WriteLine(flag); //true

        flag = cu is Client;
        Console.WriteLine(flag); // false

        //convert it to a dynamic object
        dynamic obj = cu;

        //usage of as
        var obj1 = obj as Customer;
        Console.WriteLine(obj);


        //on the below statement, I was expecting an exception on run time.#
        var obj2 = obj as Client;
        Console.WriteLine(obj2);            // <-- this is null!!

        //#checkPoint but the above line is giving me Compile time error.


        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

The "obj2" will be null, after running this code, without exceptions.

Why this works and why your code doesn't work, I don't know. I think it's based on the implementation of "as". If you use the "as" statement, then the method behind checks, whether the class are castable or not and in your case, the "as" method know's, that it is not castable and throw's an exception. But if you cast it to an dynamic object, before you use the "as", then the behind method can't check it and returns null.

Comment: Please check this link https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/532831/Use-of-Is-and-As-operators-in-Csharp